# Error :The file "files/create" does not exist laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

Web.php(route)

```
 Route::get('brand', 'BrandController@index')->name('admin.brand'); 
 Route::get('/brand/create', 'BrandController@create')->name('admin.createbrand');
```

I have define on My view :

```
<a class="btn btn-sm btn-default btn-outline btn-round" href="{{Route('admin.createbrand')}}"></a>
```

But when i have open create brand then it's type error get :

> Symfony \ Component \ HttpFoundation \ File \ Exception \ FileNotFoundException
>   The file "files/create" does not exist

[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o96uI.png)

Comment: try ti use `admin_createbrand` instead of `admin.createbrand`

Comment: sorry what you want to say i don't understand.

Comment: Route::get('/brand/create', 'BrandController@create')->name('admin_createbrand');

Comment: <a class="btn btn-sm btn-default btn-outline btn-round" href="{{Route('admin_createbrand')}}"></a>

Comment: Still it's not working :(